# std::thread instances count isn't equal to actual application threads count

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, c++11, osx-mavericks

I've created about 20 std::threads but my system monitor (Mac OS X Maveriscks along with its debugger LLDB) shows to me only five threads. What is wrong? Why if I try to create 20 threads I instead get 5 threads?

```
try
{
    std::promise<bool> prm[ 20 ] = {};
    std::thread thr[ 20 ] = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        thr[ i ] = std::thread(
            [&prm, i]() 
            {
                try
                {
                    while ( ! findPasswd() );
                    prm[ i ].set_value( true );
                }
                catch(...)
                {
                    prm[ i ].set_exception( std::current_exception() );
                }
            }
        );
        thr[ i ].detach();
    }
    for (auto & pr : prm)
    {
        pr.get_future().get();
    }
}
```

This time with `detach` i have enough of threads, but before I tried `join` instead of `detach` and had only five threads.

Comment: Let's be clear here... are you seeing _threads_ or are you seeing _processes_ in your debugger? They are very different things...

Comment: I'm clearly seeing threads with `thread list` command of LLDB.

Comment: Paste your code and debugger output?

Comment: Maybe because 15 of them have terminated?

Comment: See my edits above. It didn't fit comment constraints.

Comment: Well if you join each thread right after you create it, I don't actually see how you could have more than two threads at any time to begin with.

Comment: I don't know. When I detached threads I have exactly 20 my working threads not including service threads that 3rd party libraries start. Maybe it's because join waits for the thread to end and other threads that I saw was just service threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not to join a thread right after its creation, but to join after thread creation loop ends.